# Add attachment to Jira ticket with Azure Logic Apps

Tags: jira, azure-logic-apps, jira-rest-api

I working on a website that allows users to fill and upload files to a form. This form will be sent to Jira, creating a new ticket. I am doing this integration using Logic Apps, if the user doesn't attach any files, the Logic App works fine, but every time someone adds a file, the file is not added to the ticket but also creates a loop sending loads of emails to the user. Does anyone know how could be done? And if I need to add a function to Azure Function, could someone point me out in the right direction? :)

In the payload, the number 13 is the uploaded files

[image]

```
{
"inputs": {
    "content": "@body('HTTP')",
    "schema": {
        "properties": {
            "1": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "2": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "3": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "4": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "5": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "6": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "7": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "8": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "9": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "10": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "11": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "12": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "13": {
                "items": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "type": "array"
            },
            "14.1": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "14.2": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "14.3": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "created_by": {
                "type": [
                    "string",
                    "null"
                ]
            },
            "currency": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "date_created": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "date_updated": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "form_id": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "id": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "ip": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "is_fulfilled": {},
            "is_read": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "is_starred": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "payment_amount": {},
            "payment_date": {},
            "payment_method": {},
            "payment_status": {},
            "post_id": {},
            "source_url": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "status": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "transaction_id": {},
            "transaction_type": {},
            "user_agent": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        },
        "type": "object"
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You need to show us your flow in its current state.  Hard to help without that.

Comment: I have update with part of the workflow

Comment: You need to expand on the HTTP task in the FOR loop.  Again, hard to hep without knowing the detail.  Can you also provide the JSON payload you send to JIRA ... or whatever else needs to be sent?